# How do I make a join (joined a .csv to a shape file attribute table) permanent?

Tags: gis, arcgis

Joined population to municipalities. Now I want to work out (using field calculator in Geoprocessing) pop/km^2. However the join is not permanent so the calculation doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Joins are by default temporary. Once you have joined the two, you must save it as a new layer using "Save Layer to File". Then you will be able to use the field calculator on this new file.